# How can I open a TCP connection to a specific TCP port, send a string and read the response in Lazarus?

Tags: sockets, tcp, lazarus, freepascal

I'd like to do this without any external libraries if at all possible...

I want to open a TCP connection to a specific port on a specific IP address and then communicate by sending ANSI strings and receive an ANSI string response.

Sadly, I have no idea where to start with this, and searching the internet turns up what seem like pretty complex examples.

Can anyone give me any starting point?

Comment: If you want to use pure FPC, you can start from directory `packages\fcl-web` in your FPC installation. Another nice start point is [Category:Networking](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Category:Networking). Have fun!

Comment: Look at [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85922/5116) answer on codegolf. I think it has everything you need

Comment: Re *"ANSI string"*: Do you mean [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an excellent, free and multiplatform library called [Synapse](https://synapse.ararat.cz). It has built-in support for many protocols ([FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol), [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) and so on), and it also allows you to implement your own protocols. You can write your own clients and servers with just few lines of code—amazing!

It has excellent debug capabilities, it's very fast and code efficient. Just look at the demos in [the HOWTO area](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto).

If you like detailed information regarding Synapse with [Free Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) and [Lazarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28IDE%29) look at *[Synapse](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Synapse)* (wiki).

Comment: Although I originally wanted 'native' and had had a quick look at Synapse, this response prompted me to look again. I've now had a lot of success getting Synapse to work for me. My only remaining questions before deploying my little application are whether I need to 'disconnect' after connecting ( `socketName.Connect(IP,Port)` )and sending my request and receiving my response, and whether there is a way to check if a connection is still connected or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the socket classes available in Free Pascal. I created a simple project using these classes: *[TCP/IP client/server](https://github.com/aharoen/tcpipcomp)*

And I added three examples showing how to use it: *[tcpipcomp/demo](https://github.com/aharoen/tcpipcomp/tree/master/demo)*

Answer (score 0):

To check that the connection is still alive, you can do `SocketName.CanRead(Timeout: Integer);`

Comment: How does that answer the question? - *"How can I open a TCP connection to a specific TCP port, send a string and read the response in Lazarus?"*

Answer (score 0):

I heard you.  What you need the client's connection number.
The design of my internet chess app required this.
I created two solutions.
My solutions work but there may not be time or space to describe them here.
Before I share my solution, I want you ton know that capturing the client's RemoteAddress will not help you determine their connection number if two people on the same LAN connect to your app.
also...while Socket:TCusomSocket.Data is tempting to use...be advised that the "Data" is NOT data.  It's a pointer to data.  I tried everything I knew to associate some unque value to this data and compare it when attempting to determine the corrct client connection number and failed. You will take the same path. You might not fail, however, you will spend a lot of time learning how to use pointers.
so....here's the jist of my TCP Delphi TServerSocket/TClientSocket solution.
In a nutshell, every client has an instance of a record type and the server has an array of the same.
The sequence...

1. The server assigns a unique identifier to its newest array element when the client connects
2. The server sends this identifier back to the client preceded by "NC" (new connection).
3. The client receives the "NC" encoded message and populates the remaining fields in its record
4. the client sends the fully populated record back to the server.
5. The server updates its record to agree with the clients.
   Now they both know each other.
   Since the record on the server is indexed the same as the it connection number (zero-indexed)...to find the client connection number you locate the client identifier in the array
   On the server and client, I create a record type...
   TrecPlayer
   ConnectionID,MemberID,MemberName,Message:string[20];
   end;
   in PRIVATE on the client app, I create...
   recPlayer:TrecPlayer;

in PRIVATE on the server app, I create...
arRecPlayer:array of TrecPlayer;

THE CODE...
in the TServerSocket client connect event, I instantiate a new arRecPlayer element thusly...
arRecPlayer[x].ConnectionID := copy(CreateClassID,1,19) + '}';
then the server sends this back to the client just connected
using ServerSocket.SendText('NC' + arRecPlayer[x].ConnectionID);
The "NC" is parsed from the TClentSocket.ReceiveText and executes code...
ServerSocket.Socket.SendText('NC' + arRecPlayer[x].ConnectionID + recThisPlayer.MemberID,'any message');
when the server receives this second "NC" message, it parses the message and fills its areRecPlayer[{current connection number}].MemberID field to match that of the client.

subsequent send texts from the client have the format Directive (IS invitation Sent, IA Invitation Accpted, WO Who is Online, WRU Who Are you ..sent from the server when a client disconnects. All clients send their connection info back to the server and the active connections are restored automatically.
more...
like I said not enough time and space here.
email me at DelphiGuruSam@SamsoftUS.net

Sam